# how can I add and remove class of a element whenever it is clicked

Tags: jquery, user-interface, hyperlink, event-handling

I have created a navigation bar and options( which are icons) as `<a>`
now i want to change the css whenever one of them is selected

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 noPadding">
                <a href="?t=" id="bookfli"><div class="btn2" ><img src="img/flight_icon1.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></div></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 noPadding">
                <a href="?t=bookholidays" id="bookholi"><div class="btn1" ><img src="img/holidays_icon.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></div></a>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
<script>

    $().ready(function(){
        var bookflights,bookhotels,bookpackages,bookbus,bookholidays;

        bookholidays = $("#bookholi div");
        console.log(bookholidays);
        bookflights = $("#bookfli div");
        //var queryholi=$(document).querySelector(bookholidays);

        $("#bookholi").click(function(){


                bookholidays.removeClass("btn1").addClass("btn2");

                bookflights.removeClass("btn2").addClass("btn1");

            });

    });


</script>
```

btn1 and btn2 are two classes i want to play with.

Comment: It would be good if you give some more explanation about what is causing problem in your code?

Comment: FYI, `$().ready(handler);` is bad even in most cases it will work

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy actually when i run this code.Only problem comes the transition is just for seconds. After 0-1seconds. It comes back to its original class

Comment: @A.Wolff i know this method is old. But i dnt know how is it bad. Can you expand?

Comment: @DeWySady Check the [DOC](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), `$().ready( handler ) (this is not recommended)`. Binding `ready` pseudo handler this way don't use jQuery internal readyPromise. If you bind event this way once the document is already 'ready', then handler isn't called. The correct ways are: `$(document).ready(handler);` or `$(handler);`

Comment: yeah thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problems comes with the tag `<a>` I have used `<a>` so whenever we use a as a tag it reloads the page with different location.
The reason why it was snapping was because the tag a was refreshing the entire css and js, every time it was clicked.

So, sometimes the solution to the problem is right infrontt of you

Answer (score 1):

Try this... you might be losing the binding to "#bookholi div".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bookflights,bookhotels,bookpackages,bookbus,bookholidays;

    bookholidays = $("#bookholi");
    bookflights = $("#bookfli");

    $("#bookholi").click(function(){

        var obj = bookholidays.find('div');
        if(obj.hasClass("btn1"))
            obj.addClass("btn2").removeClass("btn1")

        else if(obj.hasClass("btn2"))
            obj.addClass("btn1").removeClass("btn2")
    });

});
```

Comment: problem is- My code is working but just for seconds like something is blocking its way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "something is blocking its way"?

Comment: what i mean is - That my code works perfectly for 0-1s then it snaps and come back to its original state. It just feels like some other code in the project might be conflicting with the above jquery.

Comment: i appreciate your support but it still the same.I guess whole project code has a confliction in it..Half baked project was passed on to me. I dnt know what did the other person do.Thanks anyways. I'll vote you up